400 Bad Request when trying to upload a file with React and send it to backend with Flask
In the site I'm building the user can upload a file (I'm using PrimeReact for the file upload), and then that file should get sent to the backend server to be used later. However, no matter what I try I'm always getting 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
Here's what I currently have:
App.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { PrimeReactProvider, PrimeReactContext } from 'primereact/api';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/mira/theme.css';
import { FileUpload } from 'primereact/fileupload';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const documentUploadHandler = ({files}) => {
    const [file] = files;
    uploadDoc(file);
  };

  const uploadDoc = async (document) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('document', document);

    try {
      let response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      let res = response.data;
      if (res.status !== 1) {
        alert('Error uploading file');
      } else {
        alert('File uploaded successfully');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('Error uploading file:', error);
      alert('Error uploading file');
    }
  };

  return (
    <PrimeReactProvider>
        <FileUpload name="document_upload" uploadHandler={documentUploadHandler} auto url={'/api/upload'} accept="image/*,application/pdf" maxFileSize={4000000} emptyTemplate={<p className="mt-[-7%]">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>} />
    </PrimeReactProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

server.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from classify_doc import *

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="*")

@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        file = request.files['document']
        print(f"Uploading document {file.filename}")
        return "done"

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Couldn't upload document: {e}")
        return "failed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)

All that gets printed into the console is
Couldn't upload document: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2024 17:54:06] "POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I'm not sure what the bad request is, since I also tried with fetch instead of axios and got the same error.

Can you provide the postman or curl request?

I actually just figured it out, turns out it had to do with the name in my FileUpload, which needs to be the same as what I'm naming the file in my post request ('document').
